# Calling JS functions from links in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

If I have a function like this:

```
function foo()
{
    //...
    return false;
}
```

I can call it like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="foo()">Run Foo</a>
```

However, in all browsers, this puts an `#` in the URL which I do not want.

So instead I do this:

```
<a href="javascript:foo()">Run Foo</a>
```

Which works fine in chrome but in IE it loads a page containing the string `false`.

Whats the best practice here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `javascript:` protocol.

```
<a href="#" onclick="foo(); return false">Run Foo</a>
```

is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Like @wrumbsy says...

> You don't need the javascript: protocol.
>
> `<a href="#" onclick="foo(); return false">Run Foo</a>`

... but this means you don't need an anchor `<a>` either. *Only use anchors for hyperlinks; not for JS-enhanced interactivity*.

A span will work just as well, with `cursor:pointer;` CSS property:

```
<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="foo(); return false">Run Foo</span>
```

Comment: But doesn't Google treat anchors differently then spans?

Comment: How so? I'd say, yes, Google does, but that's exactly why you wouldn't want to use an anchor.

Comment: @John Isaacks - ... but it's less relevant for SEO and more relevant to accessibility.